# C# Deserialize XML to SSIS Output Buffer

Tags: c#, xml, ssis, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize an xml report that is stored as text in our database.

I have declared the following classes for this via XML2CSharp.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "asic-report")]
    public class Asicreport
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "asic-name")]
        public string Asicname { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "asic-organisation-number")]
        public string Asicorganisationnumber { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "asic-a-b-n")]
        public string Asicabn { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "asic-organisation-number-heading")]
        public string Asicorganisationnumberheading { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "asic-type")]
        public string Asictype { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "asic-status")]
        public string Asicstatus { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "asic-jurisdiction")]
        public string Asicjurisdiction { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "asic-locality")]
        public string Asiclocality { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "asic-address-state")]
        public string Asicaddressstate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "asic-postcode")]
        public string Asicpostcode { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "australian-business-register-report")]
    public class Australianbusinessregisterreport
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ASICNumber")]
        public string ASICNumber { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ABN")]
        public string ABN { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ABNStatus")]
        public string ABNStatus { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ABNStatusFromDate")]
        public string ABNStatusFromDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "EntityTypeInd")]
        public string EntityTypeInd { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Non-IndividualName")]
        public string NonIndividualName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "BusinessAddressState")]
        public string BusinessAddressState { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "BusinessAddressPostcode")]
        public string BusinessAddressPostcode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GSTStatus")]
        public string GSTStatus { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GSTStatusFromDate")]
        public string GSTStatusFromDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TradingName")]
        public string TradingName { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "street-type")]
    public class Streettype
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "address")]
    public class Address
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "unit-number")]
        public string Unitnumber { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "street-number")]
        public string Streetnumber { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "property")]
        public string Property { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "street-name")]
        public string Streetname { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "street-type")]
        public Streettype Streettype { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "suburb")]
        public string Suburb { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "state")]
        public string State { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "postcode")]
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "first-reported")]
        public string Firstreported { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "bureau-report")]
    public class Bureaureport
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "address")]
        public Address Address { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "last-search-date")]
        public string Lastsearchdate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "nature-of-business")]
        public string Natureofbusiness { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ErrorMsg")]
        public string ErrorMsg { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "WarningMsg")]
        public string WarningMsg { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "bureau-reference")]
        public string Bureaureference { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "bca-company-type")]
        public string Bcacompanytype { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "bca-name")]
        public string Bcaname { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "org-id-result")]
    public class Orgidresult
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "match-name")]
        public string Matchname { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "organisation-number")]
        public string Organisationnumber { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "organisation-type")]
        public string Organisationtype { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "australian-business-number")]
        public string Australianbusinessnumber { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "organisation-number-heading")]
        public string Organisationnumberheading { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "state")]
        public string State { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "asic-report")]
        public Asicreport Asicreport { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "australian-business-register-report")]
        public Australianbusinessregisterreport Australianbusinessregisterreport { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "bureau-report")]
        public Bureaureport Bureaureport { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "response")]
    public class Response
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "org-id-result")]
        public Orgidresult Orgidresult { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "version")]
        public string Version { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "BCAservice-data")]
    public class BCAservicedata
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "response")]
        public Response Response { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "BCAservice")]
    public class BCAservice
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "BCAservice-code")]
        public string BCAservicecode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "BCAservice-code-version")]
        public string BCAservicecodeversion { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "BCAservice-client-ref")]
        public string BCAserviceclientref { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "BCAservice-data")]
        public BCAservicedata BCAservicedata { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "BCAservices")]
    public class BCAservices
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "BCAservice")]
        public BCAservice BCAservice { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "BCAmessage")]
    public class BCAmessage
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "BCAservices")]
        public BCAservices BCAservices { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "service-request-id")]
        public string Servicerequestid { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
```

I am using the following method to deserialize the xml however I cant seem to return it so I can out put it to my SSIS out put buffers.

```
 private void DeserializeStanData(string stanresponse)
    {

        string xmlStanResponseText = Convert.ToString(Variables.xmlresponse);

        XmlSerializer serializerStan = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BCAmessage));



        using (TextReader xmlResponseText = new StringReader(xmlStanResponseText))
        {
            var dsResult = serializerStan.Deserialize(xmlResponseText);

        }

        return dsResult;


    }
```

This is how I am trying to process the deserialized xml to output buffer.

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    var xmlStanResponse = Variables.xmlresponse;
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(xmlStanResponse));

    DeserializeStanData(Convert.ToString(xmlStanResponse));

    ResponseDataBuffer.AddRow();
    ResponseDataBuffer.MatchName

}
```

This is the base XML example.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<BCAmessage service-request-id="11140285673" type="RESPONSE">
    <BCAservices>
        <BCAservice>
            <BCAservice-code>BCA020</BCAservice-code>
            <BCAservice-code-version>V00</BCAservice-code-version>
            <BCAservice-client-ref/>
            <BCAservice-data>
                <response version="1-36-1">
                    <org-id-result>
                        <match-name>PATHWAYS TECHNOLOGY CONSULTING PTY LTD</match-name>
                        <organisation-number>103944976</organisation-number>
                        <organisation-type>P/L</organisation-type>
                        <australian-business-number>64103944976</australian-business-number>
                        <organisation-number-heading>ACN</organisation-number-heading>
                        <state>QLD</state>
                        <asic-report>
                            <asic-name>PATHWAYS TECHNOLOGY CONSULTING PTY LTD</asic-name>
                            <asic-organisation-number>103944976</asic-organisation-number>
                            <asic-a-b-n>64103944976</asic-a-b-n>
                            <asic-organisation-number-heading>ACN</asic-organisation-number-heading>
                            <asic-type>APTY</asic-type>
                            <asic-status>REGD</asic-status>
                            <asic-jurisdiction>ASIC</asic-jurisdiction>
                            asic-locality>FORTITUDE VALLEY</asic-locality>
                            <asic-address-state>QLD</asic-address-state>
                            <asic-postcode>4006</asic-postcode>
                        </asic-report>
                        <australian-business-register-report>
                            <ASICNumber>103944976</ASICNumber>
                            <ABN>64103944976</ABN>
                            <ABNStatus>ACT</ABNStatus>
                            <ABNStatusFromDate>2003-03-04</ABNStatusFromDate>
                            <EntityTypeInd>PRV</EntityTypeInd>
                            <Non-IndividualName>PATHWAYS TECHNOLOGY CONSULTING PTY LTD</Non-IndividualName>
                            <BusinessAddressState>QLD</BusinessAddressState>
                            <BusinessAddressPostcode>4006</BusinessAddressPostcode>
                            <GSTStatus>ACT</GSTStatus>
                            <GSTStatusFromDate>2003-03-04</GSTStatusFromDate>
                            <TradingName>INTELLIGENT PATH WAYS</TradingName>
                        </australian-business-register-report>
                        <bureau-report>
                            <address first-reported="2011-04-05" type="trading-address">
                                <unit-number>9</unit-number>
                                <street-number>515</street-number>
                                <property>GREEN SQUARE NORTH TOWER</property>
                                <street-name>ST PAULS</street-name>
                                <street-type code="TCE"/>
                                <suburb>FORTITUDE VALLEY</suburb>
                                <state>QLD</state>
                                <postcode>4006</postcode>
                            </address>
                            <last-search-date>2011-05-24</last-search-date>
                            <nature-of-business/>
                            <ErrorMsg/>
                            <WarningMsg/>
                            <bureau-reference>611723538</bureau-reference>
                            <bca-company-type>P/L</bca-company-type>
                            <bca-name>PATHWAYS TECHNOLOGY CONSULTING</bca-name>
                        </bureau-report>
                    </org-id-result>
                </response>
            </BCAservice-data>
        </BCAservice>
    </BCAservices>
</BCAmessage>
```

Comment: By the way, in your `DeserializeStanData` method, wouldn't it make more sense to have `string xmlStanResponseText = stanresponse;` instead of `string xmlStanResponseText = Convert.ToString(Variables.xmlresponse);`?

Comment: Also, depending on your XML (maybe some sample XML would be helpful), you could try `XmlSerializer serializerStan = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<BCAmessage>));`, since you might have more than 1 `BCAmessage` in your XML.

Comment: Thanks @KeyurPATEL, fair call on your first point. I will modify that. I have also added an example record for the XML.

Comment: The deserialization classes you created seem to be alright, what is the error (if any) or otherwise what does `dsResult` look like?

Comment: at `return dsResult;` the error is **"The name 'dsResult' does not exist in the current context**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your error, it seems the problem is with your function `DeserializeStanData`.

The return type is void but you return dsResult.
Also, the scope of the `dsResult` variable is the using statement only. You can't refer to it outside the using statement, because it's declared in there.

You could try changing your function as follows:

```
private BCAmessage DeserializeStanData(string stanresponse)
{
    string xmlStanResponseText = Convert.ToString(Variables.xmlresponse);
    XmlSerializer serializerStan = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BCAmessage));
    BCAmessage dsResult;
    using (TextReader xmlResponseText = new StringReader(xmlStanResponseText))
    {
        dsResult = serializerStan.Deserialize(xmlResponseText);
    }

    return dsResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a couple of issues with : DeserializeStanData.  Also xml is missing an angle bracket : FORTITUDE VALLEY //missing open angle bracket.  The code below was tested :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test test = new Test(FILENAME);

        }
    }
    public class Test
    {
        public Test(string filename)
        {
            DeserializeStanData(File.ReadAllText(filename));
        }
        private BCAmessage DeserializeStanData(string stanresponse)
        {
            BCAmessage dsResult = null;
            string xmlStanResponseText = stanresponse;

            XmlSerializer serializerStan = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BCAmessage));



            using (TextReader xmlResponseText = new StringReader(xmlStanResponseText))
            {
                dsResult = (BCAmessage)serializerStan.Deserialize(xmlResponseText);

            }

            return dsResult;


        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "asic-report")]
    public class Asicreport
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "asic-name")]
        public string Asicname { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "asic-organisation-number")]
        public string Asicorganisationnumber { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "asic-a-b-n")]
        public string Asicabn { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "asic-organisation-number-heading")]
        public string Asicorganisationnumberheading { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "asic-type")]
        public string Asictype { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "asic-status")]
        public string Asicstatus { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "asic-jurisdiction")]
        public string Asicjurisdiction { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "asic-locality")]
        public string Asiclocality { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "asic-address-state")]
        public string Asicaddressstate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "asic-postcode")]
        public string Asicpostcode { get; set; }

        public DataTable GetTable()
        {
            DataTable report = new DataTable();
            report.Columns.Add("asic-name", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("asic-organisation-number", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("asic-a-b-n", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("asic-organisation-number-heading", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("asic-type", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("asic-status", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("asic-jurisdiction", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("asic-locality", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("asic-address-state", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("asic-postcode", typeof(string));

            report.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                Asicname,
                Asicorganisationnumber,
                Asicabn,
                Asicorganisationnumberheading,
                Asictype,
                Asicstatus,
                Asicjurisdiction,
                Asiclocality,
                Asicaddressstate,
                Asicpostcode
            });
            return report;
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "australian-business-register-report")]
    public class Australianbusinessregisterreport
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ASICNumber")]
        public int ASICNumber { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ABN")]
        public string ABN { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ABNStatus")]
        public string ABNStatus { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ABNStatusFromDate")]
        public string ABNStatusFromDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "EntityTypeInd")]
        public string EntityTypeInd { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Non-IndividualName")]
        public string NonIndividualName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "BusinessAddressState")]
        public string BusinessAddressState { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "BusinessAddressPostcode")]
        public string BusinessAddressPostcode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GSTStatus")]
        public string GSTStatus { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GSTStatusFromDate")]
        public string GSTStatusFromDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TradingName")]
        public string TradingName { get; set; }

        public DataTable GetReport()
        {
            DataTable report = new DataTable();
            report.Columns.Add("ASICNumber", typeof(int));
            report.Columns.Add("ABN", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("ABNStatus", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("ABNStatusFromDate", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("EntityTypeInd", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("Non-IndividualName", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("BusinessAddressState", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("BusnessAddressPostcode", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("GSTStatus", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("GSTStatusFromDate", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("TradingName", typeof(string));

            report.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                ASICNumber,
                ABN,
                ABNStatus,
                ABNStatusFromDate,
                EntityTypeInd,
                NonIndividualName,
                BusinessAddressState,
                BusinessAddressPostcode,
                GSTStatus,
                GSTStatusFromDate,
                TradingName
            });
            return report;
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "street-type")]
    public class Streettype
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "address")]
    public class Address
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "unit-number")]
        public int Unitnumber { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "street-number")]
        public int Streetnumber { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "property")]
        public string Property { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "street-name")]
        public string Streetname { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "street-type")]
        public Streettype Streettype { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "suburb")]
        public string Suburb { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "state")]
        public string State { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "postcode")]
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "first-reported")]
        public string Firstreported { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public void GetReport(DataTable report, List<object> row)
        {
            report.Columns.Add("unit-number", typeof(int));
            report.Columns.Add("street-number", typeof(int));
            report.Columns.Add("property", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("street-name", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("Streettype-code", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("Suburb", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("state", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("postcode", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("first-reported", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("type", typeof(string));

            row.AddRange(new object[] {
                Unitnumber,
                Streetnumber,
                Property,
                Streetname,
                Streettype.Code,
                Suburb,
                State,
                Postcode,
                Firstreported,
                Type
            });


        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "bureau-report")]
    public class Bureaureport
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "address")]
        public Address Address { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "last-search-date")]
        public string Lastsearchdate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "nature-of-business")]
        public string Natureofbusiness { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ErrorMsg")]
        public string ErrorMsg { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "WarningMsg")]
        public string WarningMsg { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "bureau-reference")]
        public string Bureaureference { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "bca-company-type")]
        public string Bcacompanytype { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "bca-name")]
        public string Bcaname { get; set; }

        public DataTable GetReport()
        {
            DataTable report = new DataTable();
            report.Columns.Add("last-search-date", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("nature-of-business", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("ErrorMsg", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("WarmingMsg", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("bureau-reference", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("bca-name", typeof(string));

            List<object> row = new List<object>();
            Address.GetReport(report, row);

            row.AddRange(new object[] { 
                Lastsearchdate,
                Natureofbusiness,
                ErrorMsg,
                WarningMsg,
                Bureaureference,
                Bcaname
            });

            report.Rows.Add(row);

            return report;
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "org-id-result")]
    public class Orgidresult
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "match-name")]
        public string Matchname { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "organisation-number")]
        public long Organisationnumber { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "organisation-type")]
        public string Organisationtype { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "australian-business-number")]
        public long Australianbusinessnumber { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "organisation-number-heading")]
        public string Organisationnumberheading { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "state")]
        public string State { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "asic-report")]
        public Asicreport Asicreport { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "australian-business-register-report")]
        public Australianbusinessregisterreport Australianbusinessregisterreport { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "bureau-report")]
        public Bureaureport Bureaureport { get; set; }

        public DataTable GetReport()
        {
            DataTable report = new DataTable();
            report.Columns.Add("match-name", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("organisation-number", typeof(long));
            report.Columns.Add("organistion-type", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("australian-business-number", typeof(long));
            report.Columns.Add("organisation-number-header", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("state", typeof(string));

            report.Columns.Add("Asicorganisationnumber", typeof(int));
            report.Columns.Add("ASICNumber", typeof(int));
            report.Columns.Add("Bcaname", typeof(string));

            report.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                Matchname,
                Organisationnumber,
                Organisationtype,
                Australianbusinessnumber,
                State,
                Asicreport.Asicorganisationnumber,
                Australianbusinessregisterreport.ASICNumber,
                Bureaureport.Bcaname
            });

            return report;
        }

    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "response")]
    public class Response
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "org-id-result")]
        public Orgidresult Orgidresult { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "version")]
        public string Version { get; set; }

        public void GetReport(DataTable report, List<object> row)
        {
            report.Columns.Add("Organisationnumber", typeof(int));
            report.Columns.Add("Version", typeof(string));

            row.AddRange(new object[] {
                Orgidresult.Organisationnumber,
                Version
            });
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "BCAservice-data")]
    public class BCAservicedata
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "response")]
        public Response Response { get; set; }

        public void GetTable(DataTable report, List<object> row)
        {
            Response.GetReport(report, row );
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "BCAservice")]
    public class BCAservice
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "BCAservice-code")]
        public string BCAservicecode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "BCAservice-code-version")]
        public string BCAservicecodeversion { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "BCAservice-client-ref")]
        public string BCAserviceclientref { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "BCAservice-data")]
        public BCAservicedata BCAservicedata { get; set; }


        public void GetReport(DataTable report, List<object> row)
        {
            report.Columns.Add("BCAservicecode", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("BCAservicecodeversion", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("BCAserviceclientref", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("BCAservicedata", typeof(string));

            row.AddRange(new object[] {
                BCAservicecode,
                BCAservicecodeversion,
                BCAserviceclientref,
                BCAservicecode
            });

            BCAservicedata.GetTable(report, row);
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "BCAservices")]
    public class BCAservices
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "BCAservice")]
        public BCAservice BCAservice { get; set; }

        public void GetReport(DataTable report, List<object> row)
        {
            BCAservice.GetReport(report, row);
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "BCAmessage")]
    public class BCAmessage
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "BCAservices")]
        public BCAservices BCAservices { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "service-request-id")]
        public string Servicerequestid { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }


        public DataTable GetReport()
        {
            DataTable report = new DataTable();
            List<object> row = new List<object>();

            report.Columns.Add("Sercicerequestid", typeof(string));
            report.Columns.Add("type", typeof(string));

            BCAservices.GetReport(report, row);

            row.AddRange(new object[] {
                Servicerequestid,
                Type
            });

            return report;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks for fixing those that that has allowed it to build. However how do it get to output buffer based on data so that I can put it into a table.

Comment: You question is confusing. Are you trying to serialize or deserialize?  You said you database contains the xml as a field.So my code is taking the xml string and convert to a class object.You are now asking to store into a table. So are you asking to serialize the class object and store back to database table.Or are you referring to a different table.  What is confusing is an output buffer is usually a string or byte[].  So I assume you are referring to the serialize method.  You have no code posted for reading or writing the database.The write database methods would get string for serializer.

Comment: I have a table of data in our database that contains a text field which is raw XML. I am trying to extract that, deserialise it and then out put to tabular data. I pass the XML as a variable string xmlStanResponseText

Comment: How many tables in the tabular data?  What fields in each table?  You have a complex xml that needs multiple tables and primary keys to join the tables.

Comment: I need the reports from the response. and the primary key will be the BCAMessage service request ID. `[XmlElement(ElementName = "asic-report")]
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "australian-business-register-report")]
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "bureau-report")]` etc

Comment: I added code to build datatables.  Did not test or actually add the table to any database.  Just sample code.